# Syntax of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am quite new to stored procedures, however my project required to form a complex stored procedure.

Logically, I have some idea to do it but don't know the exact syntax and rule of stored procedure..

1. I need to while loop over a distinct attribute of a table
2. Each value of the distinct attribute bring over to query of another table as filter criteria
3. return Union table

   ```
   alter procedure dbo.someStoreProcedure
       @paramA varchar(255)
       ....

       declare @attributeA,@resultSql 

       while( (select count distinct attributeA from tableA where attributeB>@paramA and attributeB<@paramA+5)>0)//1.

       BEGIN

       @attributeA=select count distinct attributeA from tableA where         attributeB>@paramA and attributeB<@paramA+5

       @resultSql=
           select fieldA,fieldB,fieldC from tableB where fieldB=@attributeA//2,within         loop
       UNION 
           select attributeA,attributeB,attributeC from table A where attributeB=@attributeA//3


       END
   ```

return union result of (3) and (2) of each loop

Comment: You question is not clear. In the script, you have taken parameter of type `varchar` but in `while loop` you have used as if it is of numeric data type. Please try to modify your question so that people understand it easily and will be able to help you.

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - as in **stored** inside your database (it has nothing to do with a "store"). And to look up the exact syntax of something - pretty much every database vendor has **online documentation** that's freely accessible and can tell you all the details of how to write a stored procedure

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The syntax for stored procedure is very specific to the DBMS product (additionally I think you don't need a procedure at all it seems that this can be done with a single SQL statement - but to know that you will have to provide some sample data and expected output together with the table definitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whta's the target DBMS? If postgresql, I think I could rewrite your sample code like

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.someStoreProcedure(VARCHAR, VARCHAR) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS '
    DECLARE
        paramA ALIAS FOR $1;
        paramB ALIAS FOR $2;
        resultSql RECORD;
        attributeA BIGINT;
    BEGIN
        WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT attributeA) FROM tableA WHERE attributeB > paramA AND attributeB < paramA + 5) > 0)
        LOOP
            attributeA := (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT attributeA) FROM tableA WHERE attributeB > paramA AND attributeB < paramA + 5);
            FOR resultSql IN
                SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM tableB WHERE fieldB = attributeA
                UNION
                SELECT attributeA, attributeB, attribute C FROM tableA WHERE attributeB = attributeA
            LOOP
                RETURN NEXT resultSql;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END
' LANGUAGE pgplsql;
```